# Trouble with Selenium, Java, Screenshots and clicking buttons

Tags: java, button, selenium-webdriver, click

This is another question about Selenium and clicking. I have been struggling for about two days and can't get it to work - I have tried the answers in the internet and now I need a concerted effort. Thanks in Advance!!

I am working on the following site http://144.76.109.38/peTEST - this might help if you want to retrace my steps.

I am trying to fill out the login form, and then click on Login and see the answer page.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
public class toJava {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/home/tallen/RTI/lib/geckodriver/geckodriver");
                WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                driver.get("http:144.76.109.38/peTEST");
                File SF2 = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                try{
                    FileUtils.copyFile(SF2, new File("./out-004.png"));
                }catch(IOException ioe){
                        System.out.println("There was an IO error");
                }
                driver.findElement(By.id("user_login_name")).click();
                WebElement WE4 = driver.findElement(By.id("user_login_name"));
                WE4.sendKeys("Superuser");
                driver.findElement(By.id("user_password")).click();
                WebElement WE6 = driver.findElement(By.id("user_password"));
                WE6.sendKeys("Jkerouac1!");
                WebElement WE7 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@type='button'][@onclick='login()'][@value='Login']"));
                WE7.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
                File SF8 = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                try{
                        FileUtils.copyFile(SF8, new File("./out-005.png"));
                }catch(IOException ioe){
                        System.out.println("There was an IO error");
                }
                driver.quit();
        }
}
```

So basically I am opening up the page, taking a screenshot entering the user name and password, clicking Login and then taking another screenshot.

The compile and the run on this are clean - that is no exceptions and no problems. I even get two screenshots. The first screenshot shows the login page - with no data entered. The second screenshot shows the login page filled, the button I want to click marked, but not the "welcome Page" that you would get if you successfully log in. That the screenshot shows the button marked, I know that I have found the element. I have give the login info in the script, in case you want to try it out with Selenium first.

Why is the login button not being "clicked." I have tried click, perform, etc. to no avail. I have even tried putting in implicit waits - still nothing.

I have tried to Advanced Usage Interactions - and still nothing.

I am pretty new to Selenium and Java and am hoping that it is just something stupid that I am overlooking. But after looking through the Web, the solutions there are just not helping.

I am working on Debian-70-Wheezy-64-LAMP

My Selenium Libraries are from client-combined-3.0.1-nodeps.jar

My Geckodriver is v0.11.1-linux64

Thanks for the Help!!!

Comment: Assuming that the statement to click the login button is `WE7.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)`, why are you sending an Enter key to the button instead of calling `click()` on it like you do with the `user_login_name` and `user_password` fields ? I'm not necessarily saying it's wrong (I don't know and I didn't check), but I would just `click()` it instead. Also, why do you call `click()` on the `user_login_name` and `user_password` fields ? Just `sendKeys` to them.

Comment: Hi SantiBailors - this is just an evolution. I tried click() and this did not work. I saw this hint posted elsewhere on the net and so I tried it out. It works - that is, it creates no problems, but the screen shot is still incorrect, meaning that the click  did not take. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Hi,
 I don't know if it can cause a problem but anyway for the login button I would use

```
WE7.click();
```

I just think that it's easier to understand what you're trying to do with the element.

I've been working with the GeckoDriver for a while and talking with some experienced people in the area and they told me that Gecko has many problems that are not fixed yet.
They always recommended me not to use GeckoDriver because it seems to fail very often and told me to use FirefoxDriver instead.
To try it this way, and this is important, you'll just need to keep working with an older version of Firefox as the version 46 that is compatible with FirefoxDriver (that version worked for me and you can download it from places like [this](http://mozilla_firefox.en.downloadastro.com/old_versions)) and avoid using GeckoDriver.
Also the version 47 seems to work with the FirefoxDriver as I've found [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2559).
**Remember: When you install one of these previous versions of Firefox, don't forget to go to settings and disable the automatic updates and background updates because if you don't do this, you'll end soon again with the latest version that requires GeckoDriver.**

In addition you can try some validation as the following:

```
if(WE7.isDisplayed() && WE7.isEnabled()){
    WE7.click();
}
```

This kind of validations would help in case that the page isn't fully loaded at the moment that you're trying to take action over the web element. If the element is not ready, you will click it without errors but it just won't work
Hope this works for you too!

Comment: Hey thanks - I am going to try this. I need some time to try it out - will get back to you all as quickly as possible with the result.

Comment: Hey ferpel - I am going to need a bit more help - probably because I am stupid. I took a look at the firefox version running on my machine - its Mozilla Firefox 45.6.0. (I am running on a Debian-Wheezy server.

Comment: Sorry - ...so seeing that this was older that version 46, I decided to give your suggestion a try. I commented out the system set property line and could not run because I could not find firefox. So then I just copied the line at set it to /usr/bin/firefox - thinking it was to point to the firefox executable.

This also didn't work. How do I force my Selenium 3 java program to go against firefox instead of the geckodriver?

Comment: You need the code line to get to firefox and run it, just be sure you're not calling gecko instead.Write `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();` and not `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\geckodriver.exe");`

Comment: When I took out the Syste.setProperty I got a clean compile (not that I expected a compile problem) but got the following error

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases`

I am going to try playing with the marionette settings, to see if that has anything to do with the call to geckodriver

Comment: If you are using Maven [check this out](https://blog.udemy.com/selenium-ide-tutorial/) at the title "Add dependencies to the Maven pom.xml file" to be sure that you have the dependencies for the firefoxwebdriver and if you find something related to gecko remove it so that you get sure that is not searching for it anymore

Comment: Hey ferpel - well done. I was able to turn off the geckodriver and using firefox 45.6.1 could get the click done. I added following lines of code, replacing the System.setProperty for gecko: `DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities()` then `capabilities.setCapability("marionette", false);` then `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);`

Comment: What is proper Netiquette - should I add an answer with the full code that works?